# Not able to send email to sendgrid python

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, sendgrid

my send_mail code

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from middleware.response import success, bad_request
from user.serializer.dao import SendEmailDao
from core.models import EmailLeadLogs
from util.email import send_mail


class SendEmailView(APIView):

    def post(self, request):
        attributes = SendEmailDao(data=request.data)
        if not attributes.is_valid():
            return bad_request(attributes.errors)

        email_lead_logs = EmailLeadLogs(**attributes.data["meta"])
        email_lead_logs.subject = attributes.data["subject"]
        email_lead_logs.save()

        send_mail(attributes.data["email"].split(","), attributes.data["subject"], attributes.data["message"])

        return success({}, "email send successfully", True)
```

This is the error i am getting, I am trying to use it from drf

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NboOI.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's important to make sure your email settings are wired up correctly in `settings.py`. Here are the options I use when configuring Sendgrid (you may not need them all):

```py
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'myemail@email.com'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.sendgrid.net'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'apikey'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD')
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
ACCOUNT_CONFIRM_EMAIL_ON_GET = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX = 'Hello'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'optional'
```

`EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD` is the API key that Sendgrid gives you.